# Wordpress(wpdb class) and mysql stored procedures

Tags: wordpress

```
$query = "CALL ..........";
$result = $wpdb->get_results($query);
print_r($results);
```

Is returning an empty array, how do you run stored procedures from the $wpdb class?

Answer (score -1):

I'm not 100% sure since I've not worked with stored procs in MySQL yet *(although I have coded many a stored-proc for MS-SQL in the 90's)*, but try:

```
global $wpdb;
$wpdb->query('CALL ...');
print_r($wpdb->last_result);
```

Whatever you pass to `$wpdb->query()` gets passed to [the PHP `mysql_query()` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) so whatever works there will work with WordPress' `$wpdb->query()`. I do know this works:

```
global $wpdb;
$wpdb->query('SELECT * FROM wp_posts LIMIT 10');
print_r($wpdb->last_result);
```

If you want to read the source code for `$wpdb->query()` to further understand what is happening you can find it in `/wp-includes/wp-db.php` at lines 1057-1153 in v3.01.

Hope this helps.

-Mike

P.S. You might want to check out StackOverflow's sister site [WordPress Answers](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com) next time you need help with WordPress. Lots of WordPress enthusiasts are on hand over there to answer your WordPress questions.

Comment: Small update: `$wpdb->last_result` will be [deprecated in WP 3.1](http://wpdevel.wordpress.com/2010/11/12/if-you-were-using-wpdb-last_result-yo/), you should use `$wpdb->get_results()` to get the last result.

Comment: @Jan Fabry - Yeah I saw that after posting this answer. Unfortunately `$wpdb->get_results()` doesn't work with v3.0.